# Is covariance pca on standardized dataset equal to correlation pca on the original dataset?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, pca

would the following four methods be different?

1. original data -> covariance on orginal data -> pca
2. normalizing data -> covariance on normalized data -> pca
3. original data -> correlation on orginal data -> pca
4. normalizing data -> correlation on normalized data -> pca

I reckon that 1,2 should be significantly different if variables are scaled differently.
But should 2,3 be the same thing?
and what would 4 mean?